# Step in proof of derivation of $1+2+\cdots+n=\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, proof-explanation, arithmetic-progressions

I have been solving a few computer science problems lately and it is important for me to understand how the time complexity of an algorithm is calculated by coming up with the derivation and arriving at the result. One problem is frustrating me a lot.

In order to find the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers I can use the equation $\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.
I looked into [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180228100040/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57990.html) and understand how this equation makes sense.

And then I looked into [this article](https://r-knott.surrey.ac.uk/runsums/triNbProof.html) to understand how to arrive at this equation via algebraic method.

[image]

I feel like there is a giant leap between the third and second lines from the last in the above image. This is the same derivation I could find in all the articles i have visited.
I don't understand how the equation suddenly got multiplied with $n$ on the right hind side, where  $2T(n)= n(n+1)$.

Kindly let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: How many (n+1)s are added together on the 3rd from last line?

Comment: The author writes the two lines of the sum on on top of the other in order to highligt the "pattern": 1 and n, 2 and n-1, 3 and n-2, and so on. Then he sums the pairs...

Comment: @MatthewTowers n times.i feel so stupid. thank you n times :)

Comment: If you add up $(n+1)$ a total of $n$ times the result is .... what?  If you add up $k + k+ ..... +k$ a total of $m$ times the result is $m\times k$.  ANd if you add up $(n+1) + (n+1) + .... + (n+1)$ a total of $n$ times the result is.... $n\times (n+1)$.

Comment: In blue the author says "All the n pair-sums or equal to n+1".  By "n pair-sums" he is attempting to draw attention to there being  $n$ of them.  Perhaps it may have been clearer had he said:  "There are $n$ pair-sums and each of them is equal to $n+1$".  Also in the line of above he writes "pair off the terms; a red with a green".  Perhaps he should have added "There will be $n$ of these pairs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative. $\color{white}{You shall never see me.}$

See this sum?

$S=1+\color{red}{2}+\color{blue}{3}+\color{green}{4} \ldots \color{orange}{n}$

Write it backwards.

$S=n+\color{red}{(n-1)}+\color{blue}{(n-2)}+\color{green}{(n-3)} \ldots \color{orange}{1}$

Add up corresponding terms:

$2S=(n+1)+(n-1+2)+(n-2+3) \ldots (1+n)$

$=n(n+1)$

That's what the article is saying.

Answer (score 1):

On the right hand side you have a sum of $n$ terms, and each terms equals $n+1$, so this sum equals $n(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Does this layout help?:

$T(n) + T(n) = \underbrace{1 + 2 + 3 + ...... + n}_{\text{There are }n\text{ of these terms}} + $

$\underbrace{n + (n-1)+ (n-2) + ...... + 1}_{\text{These are }n\text{ of these terms}}=$

$\underbrace{(1+n) + (2+n-1)+ (3+ n-2) + ...... + (n+1)}_{\text{These are }n\text{ of these terms}}=$

$\underbrace{(n+1) + (n+1)+ (n+1) + ...... + (n+1)}_{n\text{ times}}=$

$n\times (n+1)$

.....

Remember $m \times k= \underbrace{k + k + k + ..... +  k}_{m \text{ times}}$.

That's why we call it "times".  Because $m$ "times" $k$ means we add $k$ to itself $m$ **times**.

Comment: yes. thank you for this layout